# How to select which button to click on Robotium for an alert dialog?

Tags: android, robotium, android-alertdialog

I am new to Robotium. I have created an alert dialog box using dialog builder and called it using the show command. I was able to trigger the 'ok' button by default using Robotium and I am not able to do the same for the 'cancel' button. As the dialog box is not associated with an id, I am not sure how to get the id of the buttons. Here is my code for the dialog box

```
alertDialogBuilder
.setMessage("Please enter only numbers without any spaces")
.setCancelable(true)
.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
 dialog.cancel();
 }
 })
 .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
 dialog.cancel();
 }
 });
```

The code I used to trigger the 'ok' button in the Test Class is

```
 solo.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
 solo.getCurrentActivity().getCurrentFocus().requestFocus();
 }
 });
 this.sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER);
```

How to do the same for the 'cancel' button? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use solo.clickOnButton("Cancel");

Comment: ya. had it fixed. Thanks Renas

Answer (score 22):

Actually, I suggest you do `solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(buttonId))` where the 'Positive' button is `android.R.id.button1`, the 'Negative' button is `android.R.id.button2` and 'Neutral' is `android.R.id.button3`.

Comment: This has proved much more reliable for me than the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: what if we have custom dialog??